# How do I download a package on a USB device?

Tags: python, pycharm

So I am just beginning to learn Python and I was wondering whether it is possible to install a package onto a USB drive instead of onto the device itself. I wanted to download a package but I didn't have enough storage to install it. So I put the project into a USB drive and opened the project and tried to download the package hoping it would use the storage in the USB, which it didn't. Is there a way to do this or do packages need to take up the storage of the device instead? For context, I am using PyCharm.

I tried to look for advice on youtube and here, but I can't seem to find any, or I just do not know what to look for. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages are installed in the base environment of Python itself, not in your project.

I think you can achieve your goal by creating a new virtual environment on your USB drive. Then install all the required packages into that virtual environment and run your code.

In the bottom right of PyCharm you probably see "Python 3.x ...". Click on that, then "New Interpreter" > "Add Local Interpreter". This brings up the environment menu, in which you can indicate where a new environment should be created, and with which manager. I prefer Conda, but Virtualenv should work fine for you. Once that is set up you can install the packages from PyCharm as long as this new environment is activated (indicated in the bottom right of the main screen).